# Hide scrollbar (with scroll enabled)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with 2 columns and multiple rows

```
<table border=0 id="feed">
    <tr><td>something</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="">something1</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="">something2</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="">something3</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="">something4</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="">something5</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>something-else1</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>something-els2</td><td><div class="bubble"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to scroll down without showing the scrollbar (implying that the total height of the rows exceed the 800px limit) . I am looking for a Chrome/Firefox compatible fix.

Current properties of *feed*:

```
  #feed{
    display: block;height: 800px;overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This only works on the chrome framework:

```
#feed::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried adding a parent to the table (according to [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll/16671476#16671476)):

```
#outer{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:800px;
}
#feed{overflow:scroll;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="outer"><table border=0 id="feed">...</table></div>
```

Please note that the total height is bigger than 800px so scrolling should work. It does not, though.

Comment: How are you expecting people to scroll (or even know that there is hidden content that can be scrolled to) without showing a scroll bar? `overflow: hidden` would seem to fit what you want, but it would be terrible UX.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/1577396)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, that disables the scroll capability. In the context I work in, the existence of the "hidden content" can be deducted upon scrolling a list of msgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#feed{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-right: -30px;
}

#outer{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I used 100px height because of my small table :)

Comment: I know it has been years but: you might want to use some right padding on the feed-element to abstract away that even in the same browser, scrollbars may differ in width depending on the OS (firefox+ubuntu for example has 10px); that may not matter in every case but if you want to show a list of items with rounded borders, you might cut off the right side without a padding, producing an inconsistent look.

Answer (score 0):

```
#feed{
    display: block;
    height: 800px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```