# How can I hide the scrollbar but keep the functionality for my overflowing table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I created a table which has a container that has a specific max height. I want to keep the scroll functionality for the overflowing table, but hide the scrollbar itself.

I tried some solutions that are present on the internet, but couldn't make this work.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
<table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Columna</th>
        <th>Relative</th>
        <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Coloumn</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>is</td>
        <td>not equals</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>the</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Coloumn</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#codexpl th, #codexpl td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#codexpl th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#container {
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

This is the jsfiddle I created to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6rp1vsh/

**Edit**:
The browser where the website needs to run in is Opera version 11 which does not support the newest features!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scrollbar (with scroll enabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194382/hide-scrollbar-with-scroll-enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the snippet. Let me know if you have any doubt.

```css
#codexpl th, #codexpl td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#codexpl th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: unset;
}

table#codexpl {
    display: block;
    width: 105%;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Columna</th>
        <th>Relative</th>
        <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>is</td>
        <td>not equals</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>the</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: See snippet in Full page.

Comment: This one works in the browser I am developing for, Opera version 11, great!

Comment: Thanks. If you satisfy with my answer then please vote up on the answer.

Comment: The only thing I do not like is the width property of 105 percent

Answer (score 1):

add this in the css file

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry to say but this does not work in Opera v11

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to set the scrollbar width to 0

```
#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry to say but this does not work in Opera v11

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
::-webkit-scrollbar ::-webkit-scrollbar-track ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry to say but this does not work in Opera v11

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it easily using CSS.

**To hide the scrollbars, but still be able to keep scrolling, you can use the following code:**

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE and Edge */
.hide-scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

I've created this fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/u105fbx4/

Add `class="hide-scrollbar"` to your DIV , like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="hide-scrollbar">
```

and this to the **end of CSS FILE**:

```
 .hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }

    .hide-scrollbar {
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
    }
```